# Vue.js Scroll Snap to Component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, scroll-snap

I'm trying to scroll snap to components in Vue.js 3. I can get scroll snap to work correctly with vanilla HTML and CSS. Here's what it looks like: [Scroll Snap Demo](https://codepen.io/123samueld/pen/VwmyqZB)

I'm trying to copy that simple layout but using App.js as the container and components as the divs. Here's what it looks like in App.vue:

```
<template class="container">
    <CompI class="snapAlign"/>
    <CompII class="snapAlign"/>
    <CompIII class="snapAlign"/>
    <CompIV class="snapAlign"/>
</template>

<script>
import CompI from './components/CompI.vue'
import CompII from './components/CompII.vue'
import CompIII from './components/CompIII.vue'
import CompIV from './components/CompIV.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    CompI,
    CompII,
    CompIII,
    CompIV
  }
}
</script>

<style>
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.container{
overflow-y: scroll;
scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}
.snapAlign{
scroll-snap-align: start;
}
</style>
```

Here's what I've got for components, they're all basically the same as each other:

```
<template>
  <div class="one">
    <h1>One</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'CompI'
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.one{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: green;
}
</style>
```

I also tried using vue-scroll-snap but it doesn't seem to work on components the way the guides show it working on divs. This was the guide I tried: [Vue Scroll Snap Guide](https://www.vuescript.com/one-page-scroll-with-auto-snapping-vue-scroll-snap/)

Here's what I've got for App.vue using that method:

```
<template>
  <vue-scroll-snap >
    <CompI/>
    <CompII/>
    <CompIII/>
    <CompIV/>
  </vue-scroll-snap>
</template>

<script>
import CompI from './components/CompI.vue'
import CompII from './components/CompII.vue'
import CompIII from './components/CompIII.vue'
import CompIV from './components/CompIV.vue'

import VueScrollSnap from "vue-scroll-snap"

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    CompI,
    CompII,
    CompIII,
    CompIV,
    VueScrollSnap
  }
}
</script>

<style>
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

The components are the same as the other method.

The pages appear correctly but there's no scroll snap effect with either of these attempts. I'd like to try and use the components as full screen elements to snap to, the app will scale better like that.

+++ Solution +++

Ivo Gelov was correct, remove the class from `<template>`, place the components inside a div and give it the class "container". For some reason that alone wasn't enough, more style was needed on that class then it works. Here's the final CSS for that class:

```
.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}
```

Comment: `<template` does not support a `class` prop - you will have to add the class to the actual DOM node that contains your components.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what a DOM node is, could you add a little more detail?

Comment: You should wrap CompI/II/III/IV inside a DIV and assign the class `container` to it rather than to the `<template`

Comment: Thank you. I gave that a shot, didn't work. Inspecting the elements with dev tools show's correct CSS on the container and component divs but it's not snapping.

Answer (score 1):

Go to index.html and add this below the HTML part:

```html
<style>
html,
body {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}
</style>
```

Then go to App.vue and just simply add this to every component:

```
scroll-snap-align: start;
```

It should do the trick.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't touched Vue.JS in years now, so I can't confirm if that's the solution or not. I'll leave it up incase it helps someone else searching a similar question on StackOverflow.